# iOS SpriteKit Coordinates problems with origin

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

I've been playing around with SpriteKit, because I want to create a game in a year, but I caught some speed bumps lately in a weird form.

So this is the issue.

I have created a regular SpriteKit project and I've changed some default code.
I added a SKNode with the size of 20,20 (square) to the position 0,0 or CGPointZero.

The thing is, my displayed resolution is 1024x768 and if I run my app in landscape I can't see my square in the 0,0 point, I can only see it if I set the Y position to 100, like

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
```

and if I run my app in portrait mode, the Y axis if fixed, the 0 will be on the left hand corner, but I can't see the square once again , unless I set my X position to 300 like

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 0)
```

Why can't I simply see the node on the 0,0 position no matter which screen orientation I'm facing.

Here goes my full class

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let myNode = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        myNode.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        myNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        myNode.color = UIColor.blackColor()
        myNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        myNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
        myNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        myNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        myNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        myNode.zPosition = 1
        addChild(myNode)



    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
            let moveToY = touch.locationInNode(self).y
            myNode.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(moveToY, duration: 5))
        }


    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        //print("Position Y: \(self.myNode.position.y)")
    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you expect your node to be? By default the origin of your scene is in the lower left corner. This is different from UIKit where the origin would be the upper left corner. But also the dimensions of your scene are most likely larger than the device you're testing on.

Comment: I'd expect so see it on the lower left corner. How can I set the scene dimensions to the size of the screen, no matter which device I'm using? I've tested on iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus e and the issue maintain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and set the scene size in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` in your view controller.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {    
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    let scene = YourGameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Hope this helps.
**Edit:** Don't set the scene size in `viewDidLoad()`, because the view size will not be correct if phone changed the orientation. Set the scene size in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` ensures that the view size is adjusted correctly based on phone's orientation.

Comment: Ooohhhh.... That's it. I'm setting its size in the regular viewDidLoad() instead of the method you've said. I'll try it the way you said , but I'm sure it will work. I'll set this as the correct answer. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Oh my, you have no idea how much this answer have helped me. Setting the scene to the same size as the view solved all my coordinate issues. Thank you for this!